# Pass filename to PrintDialog.PrintDocument

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, printing

I have a flowdocument and need to write it to a PDF file. With the below code a dialog opens up asks for the file name and then the pdf gets generated.

```
var flowDocument = documentTemplate.LoadContent() as FlowDocument;
flowDocument.PageWidth = printDialog.PrintableAreaWidth;
flowDocument.PageHeight = printDialog.PrintableAreaHeight;
var paginator = new HeaderFooterPaginator<HeaderModel, FooterModel>(0, flowDocument, GetHeader(), GetFooter());
printDialog.PrintDocument(paginator, "My Document");
```

**But if a pdf with the same exists and it's open then this code crashes.** How do I pass a filename to PrintDocument function ?

Edit:
I'm aware of catching the exception. Now after the exception is thrown I want the filename to have datetime included in it.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256517/discussion-on-question-by-harxish-pass-filename-to-printdialog-printdocument); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

@BionicCode comment as answer:

Asking the user to give another filename when exception happens.

```cs
bool isRetryRequired = false;

// Avoid infinite loops --> while(true)
do 
{
  try
  {
    printDialog.PrintDocument(paginator, "My Document");
  }
  catch (IOException e)
  {
    // The exception thrown when a file is locked is the 'IOException', 
    // which is also the base class for more specialized I/O exceptions.
    // Check if the exception is not derived from IOException. 
    // More specialized cases like FileLoadException must be handled explicitly. 
    // Such exceptions are not necessarily the responsibility of 
    // user controllable parameters or can't be fixed by the user. 
    // It's recommended to rethrow those exceptions.
    Type exceptionType = e.GetType();
    bool exceptionIsSubClassOfIoException = exceptiontype.BaseType == typeof(IOException);
    if (exceptionIsSubClassOfIoException)
    {
      // Rethrow more specialized exception
      throw;
    }

    /*** 
         Exception is a pure IOException and *could* be thrown due to a locked file.
         This exception is not a derived and more specialized type 
         that we can handle more specifically. 
    ***/

    string errorMessage = 
$@"Unable to save the PDF document to the specified file.
Maybe the file is write-protected or is used by another process.

Do you want to retry?";
   
    string dialogTitle = "Printing error";
    var dialogResult = MessageBox.Show(
      errorMessage, 
      dialogTitle, 
      MessageBoxButton.OKCancel, 
      MessageBoxImage.Error);
            
    isRetryRequired = result == MessageBoxResult.Ok;
  }    
} while (isRetryRequired);
```

Comment: No this is not exactly what I was saying. I was adding that you should not handle `Exception` but `IOException` instead. And because `IOException`itself is the base class for e.g. `FileNotFoundException` you must check the type and rethrow it if it is a more derived type e.g. `FileNotFoundException`. The error message has to be more vague too. At this point we don't know for sure if the exception (`IOException`) is thrown because of accessing a locked file.  We must kind of communicate this uncertainty e.g. by naming a few chances for this error in the error message for the user.

Comment: I have updated your post to show what I meant. Exception handling is important. For example, you current catch block would also handle an `ArgumentException` which is definitely not what you want. The user can't fix the `ArgumentException`. Such an exception must crash the application so that the developer can fix it. Just *never* catch `Exception`. That's common best practice.

Comment: [Best practices for exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions), [Exceptions Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/exceptions/#exceptions-overview)